# TCP calculate checksum

Tags: networking, tcp, checksum, calculation

I am trying to calculate the checksum of the following packet:
[A TCP packet captured with wire shark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTrCW.png)

But I never managed to get the correct checksum (0x67ea).

I tried to calculate it like follows (of course with using one's complement sum):

> source IP + destination IP + TCP protocol + (TCP header length +
> payload length) + payload

> c0a8 + ae80 + c0a8 + ae01 + 0006 + 0026 + 6c69 + 646f + 720a = 420df
>
> With the one's complement: 4 + 20df = 20e3
>
> not(20e3) = df1c

Which is defiantly not the current checksum.

I also notice that every time I send the same payload, the checksum is changing so I guess it can't be those same unchanging variables and it must be more (for example timestamp..).

What are the exact parameters and the formula that checksum uses?
and how can I calculate it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might've overlooked TCP fixed header and TCP options. These bytes also contribute to the checksum (not just TCP payload). Please note that the TCP checksum field (`ddff`) is replaced with `0` for correct calculation.

```
IPv4 SRC + IPv4 DST + IPv4 Protocol + TCP Segment Length +

TCP Fixed Header (with checksum field set to 0) +

TCP Options +

TCP Payload
```

gives you

```
c0a8 + ae80 + c0a8 + ae01 + 0006 + 0026 +

115c + dcba + 28d5 + 41da + 64e8 + 6a10 + 8018 + 01fe + 0000 + 0000 +
                                                       (csum)

0101 + 080a + 5c86 + c6f8 + bd62 e36f + 

6c69 + 646f + 720a
```

which equals `9980c`. Next, `9 + 980c = 9815`, and, finally, this will give you `67ea`.

Comment: TCP segment length= : The length of the TCP segment, including both header (20B)and options(12B) and data(6B)=38B= `ox0026`